# Hangfire .Net Core 404

Tags: .net-core, hangfire

We are trying to use hangfire with .Net core deployed to linux box. We are able to locally run and view the Hangfire Dashboard, and other pages like retiries, jobs etc. But when we deploy the code, we are seeing the dashboard, but all the css and js and links are pointing to domain/hangfire/ instead of domain/appname/hangfire.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    IConfigurationService confiuration = (IConfigurationService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IConfigurationService));
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        var pathBase = context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-PathBase"];
        context.Request.PathBase = new PathString(pathBase);
        return next();
    });

    app.UseCors(builder =>
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());

    if (!env.IsProduction())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) => swaggerDoc.BasePath = Configuration["Swagger:BasePath"]);
    });

    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint(Configuration["Swagger:JSONLocation"], "My Scheduler API V1");
        c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None);
    });
    app.UseAuthentication();
    //app.UseMiddleware<BasicAuthMiddleware>(confiuration.ApplicationUri);
    app.UseBasicAuthentication(confiuration.ApplicationUri);

    var options = new DashboardOptions
    {
        Authorization = new[] { new HangfireAuthorizationFilter() }
    };
    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", options);
    app.UseHangfireServer();

    SchedulerInitializer.InitializeScheduler(confiuration);

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: DId you tried changing `appname/hangfire` while invoking UseHangfireDashboard ? I guess it will work as per the documentation http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html

Comment: I am also facing the same error. I did try appname/hangfire, but still, it didn't work.

Comment: I am also receiving the 404.0 Error. Hangfire worked fine before I installed swagger, swashbuckle, and nswag.